# I am deploying smart contract of 23 kb on Hedera Previewnet, But it gives error "HardhatError: HH110: Invalid JSON-RPC response received"

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, hardhat, hedera-hashgraph

I am having an issue in deploying the smart contract with a size of 23.4 kb on Hedera Preview net using hardhat.

Below is the error

**HardhatError: HH110: Invalid JSON-RPC response received:**

**502 Server Error

Error: Server Error

The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.**

If I try to deploy another smart contract of a smaller size successfully deploy it on Previewnet.

How can I deploy a larger smart contract of more than 20 kb? I have tried hasgraph sdk as well.  I highly appreciate your help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You cannot. It has a max bytecode size of `24,576 bytes`

Comment: @RobinThomas, Thanks for your reply. 

The smart contract size is less than 24.

Comment: Can you share your `hardhat.config.*` and the script you use to deploy?

Comment: @RobinThomas, There was an issue with the Hedera TestNet network. I have successfully deployed all smart contracts. 
Thanks for your support :)